# How do I record a song that is already playing in audacity?

Tags: recording, audio-editing, audacity

I am using the recent version of Audacity in Windows and I want to apply some effects to my audio(song). This effect is real-time and I have to record the audio while applying this effect. How to do this,help?

Comment: what is exactly the problem? can't you play back the song by adiocity applying this effect,  record the song with audiocity and export it as mp3 or wave file? That's the way I would do it with finale.

Comment: I will try your method and tell if it worked or not.

Comment: then ask below my answer what's wrong there that has been downvoted. ;)

Comment: I didn't do it, I am just a beginner. I have no privileges.

Comment: Please could you specify what effects you want to apply? Then perhaps we can tell you whether or not there is a way to apply them while you are recording.

Comment: Ambeo orbit for binaural sound

Answer (score 1):

Just play back the song by adiocity applying this effect

record the song with audiocity

export it as mp3 or wave file? That's the way I would do it with finale.

otherwise This should work by linking with a mini jack plug the audio-out with audio-in and recording with any wave software as audacity.